# Reference Angular/Ionic component from another file without adding a directive for it

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following Angular/Ionic component inside `field.html`:

```html
<ng-template #mainField let-uiComponent>
    <ion-label position="stacked">{{uiComponent.getAttribute("DISPLAY_NAME")}}</ion-label>
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]='uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_TYPE")'>
        <ion-input  *ngSwitchCase="'NUMBER'" type="number" value='{{uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_DISPLAY_VALUE")}}' ></ion-input>

        <ion-datetime *ngSwitchCase="'DATE'" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY" value='{{uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_DISPLAY_VALUE")}}' ></ion-datetime>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #checkboxField let-uiComponent>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{uiComponent.getAttribute("DISPLAY_NAME")}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox checked="{{fieldValue}}" value="uiComponent.getAttribute('FIELD_NAME')" slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ng-template>

<ng-container [ngSwitch]='uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_TYPE")'>

    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'CHECKBOX'" >
        <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="checkboxField; context:{ $implicit: uiComponent }"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="mainField; context:{ $implicit: uiComponent }">
        </ng-container> 
    </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

In this component we have multiple templates to draw a field based on a certain type. The component works fine, but when we add a lot of field types (let us say 15 types) the code becomes hard to track. Therefore, we decided to separate each field type into a dedicated file and created the following component `checkbox.html`:

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{uiComponent.getAttribute("DISPLAY_NAME")}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox checked="{{fieldValue}}" value="uiComponent.getAttribute('FIELD_NAME')" slot="start"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

and updated our field component to be as follows:

```html
<ng-template #mainField let-uiComponent>
    <ion-label position="stacked">{{uiComponent.getAttribute("DISPLAY_NAME")}}</ion-label>
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]='uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_TYPE")'>
        <ion-input  *ngSwitchCase="'NUMBER'" type="number" value='{{uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_DISPLAY_VALUE")}}' ></ion-input>

        <ion-datetime *ngSwitchCase="'DATE'" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY" value='{{uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_DISPLAY_VALUE")}}' ></ion-datetime>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-container [ngSwitch]='uiComponent.getAttribute("FIELD_TYPE")'>

    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'CHECKBOX'" >
            <field-checkbox [uiComponent]="uiComponent"></field-checkbox>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="mainField; context:{ $implicit: uiComponent }">
        </ng-container> 
    </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

After that we noticed that an extra HTML element `field-checkbox` was added to the UI, see it highlighted on the below screenshot:
[image]

How can we refactor the code to separate different UI components but without having this element to be added to the UI? This is important since it breaks some CSS when adding that extra element to the UI.

Comment: did you try the Dynamic component?
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 1):

It might not be possible as breaking down a component into several small components will definitely add a new tag. In your example: `field-checkbox`.

I think you need to solve the css styling issue so that it doesn't break. For example
Target any child element rather than direct decendents in your css rules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
The problem that the CSS rules is form ionic framework, so i do not want to fix the framework styles.